# Playing sections of a movie

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

Is it possible to play sections of a movie without using timers to do the pausing and unpausing? For example I have a movie loaded into MPMoviePlayerController, the user taps and the first section of the movie is played then the movie is paused, on the second tap another section is played and so on. Setting the initialPlayBackTime and endPlayBackTime of MPMoviePlayerController doesn't help as endPlayBackTime gets updated only when stop is called (could it be a bug?), but stopping causes an annoying flicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think so... You need the timer and that's it.